# How can I execute a testsuite containing multiple flows?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

How can I execute a testsuite containing mulitple flows in PAF?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To execute multiple flows, you should put the flow ids in init file as flow.ids=.Each flow id should be separated by comma(,)
and each flow will be executed once if loop.flow = 1

Eg:
flow.ids=flow1,flow2,flow3
All the flows should be in the same .xml file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).